# php error message: Warning: implode(): invalid arguments passed

Tags: php

I have added an email contact form to my site using a guide from here:

https://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/email.html

It works fine, except for the following error message that appears on the page:

```
Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in /var/www/vip6/sites/vip4092987/httpd/htdocs/email.php on line 130
```

And the offending code:

```
<?php
        # Shift back into PHP mode for a moment to display
        # the error message, if there was one
        if (count($messages) > 0) {
                $message = implode("<br>\n", $messages);
                echo("<h3>$message</h3>\n");
        }
?>
```

I've tried contacting the author site without any response, how do I resolve this?

Comment: Run `var_dump($messages);` to verify it contains what you think it contains.

Comment: As others have said, check what `$messages` contains. Most likely it only has 1 element, and since php is (mostly) dynamically typed its not going to be seen as an array when passed into `implode()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implode function need an array as the second argument, looks like in your case $messages variable is not an array

Check what messages content is

```
var_dump($messages)
```

Also can try to cast type:

```
$message = implode("<br>\n", (array)$messages);
```

But proper solution depends on an actual value of $messages variable

Comment: Thank you for your answer, adding (array) has resolved the problem.